# MongoDB as Time Series database: inserting "old" data between existing times

Tags: mongodb, time, insert, series

I'm looking into using MongoDB as a time-series database. Once conern I have is that my application will require the ability to go back in time and fill in gaps in the time-series data. For example, I might have data at times 1, 2, 3, 6. After time 10 has been reported, I might then need to insert data for times 4, 5, 6. Will inserting the data be practical or will I suffer a big performance hit by needing to use slow/complex operations? Will updating time 6 with the same (or possibly new) value be straightforward or will different operations be required to insert new data then update existing data?

Comment: If you're using an index for the time field, the general order of insertion shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Using the update and upsert flags this is easily done (MongoDB is awesome!).
Below is some sample python code that does this.

```
import time
import datetime
import random
import csv
import os
import zipfile
import json
import pymongo
from pymongo import Connection

client = Connection('localhost')
db = client.pan2
collection = db.well1

maxloop = 10000
x = 1
y = random.randint(100,999)/random.randint(1,10)
v1 = 'value'+str(random.randint(1,10))
v2 = 'value'+str(random.randint(1,10))
v3 = 'value'+str(random.randint(1,10))

elaptime = time.clock()

while maxloop > 0:
    collection.update({'timestamp': x}, {'$set': {'value1':y, v1 : y/2, v2 : y/4}}, upsert=True)
    maxloop = maxloop - 1
    x = x + 1

elaptime=elaptime-time.clock()*-1
print("Processing time was", elaptime, "seconds")
```